# Как сделать комиссию при переводе денег другому пользователю MongoDB

Tags: discord.py

Здравствуйте меня интересует вопрос как можно сделать комиссию при переводе денег другому пользователю на баланс с использованием базы-данных MongoDB?

Вот код куда я бы хотел вставить комиссию при переводе:

````
@commands.command(aliases = ['перевести'])
    async def pay(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
        if self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})["balance"] < amount:
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"__{ctx.author}__, у вас не достаточно средств"))
        else:
            if amount is None:
                await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму, которую желаете начислить на счет пользователя")
            elif amount < 1:
                await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму больше 1 <:emoji_71:880899034750013513>")
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "**Передача средств**", description = f"**Отправитель:**{ctx.author}\n**Получатель:**{member}\n——————————\n**Сумма: {amount}**"))
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id}, {"$inc": {"balance": -amount}})

                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": member.id}, {"$inc": {"balance": +amount}})
            
                await ctx.add_reaction('✅')
    ```
````

Comment: вычислить `service_fee`, проверить есть ли на счету отправителя сумма большая или равная `amount + service_fee`, списать `amount + service_fee`, зачислить `amount`. хозяйке на заметку: фискируете транзакцию, а то при разборках никогда не сможете обосновать откуда у кого какие деньги появились и списались

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работал с данной дб, но вам надо в апдейте денег автора сделать не `- amount`, а `- (amount + комиссия)`

```
@commands.command(aliases = ['перевести'])
    async def pay(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
        if self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})["balance"] < amount:
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"__{ctx.author}__, у вас не достаточно средств"))
        else:
            if amount is None:
                await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму, которую желаете начислить на счет пользователя")
            elif amount < 1:
                await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, укажите сумму больше 1 <:emoji_71:880899034750013513>")
            else:
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "**Передача средств**", description = f"**Отправитель:**{ctx.author}\n**Получатель:**{member}\n——————————\n**Сумма: {amount}**"))
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id}, {"$inc": {"balance": -(amount + service_fee)}})

                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": member.id}, {"$inc": {"balance": +amount}})
            
                await ctx.add_reaction('✅')
```

Comment: а мне нужно указать чему равно service_fee?

Comment: конечно нужно, а как иначе?